# How can I get a consistent argument from jQuery.when() whether a single Deferred is passed to it or multiple

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery.when() to batch paginated calls to a JSON API. I don't know how many calls I the pagination will make, but I need to concatenate the results into a single array. The problem I have is that jQuery.when() behaves differently depending on whether **a single** deferred/promise arguments are passed, or **multiple arguments** are passed. Per the [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/):

- If a single Deferred is passed to jQuery.when(), its Promise object
  (a subset of the Deferred methods) is returned by the method.
- In the
  case where multiple Deferred objects are passed to jQuery.when(), the
  method returns the Promise from a new "master" Deferred object that
  tracks the aggregate state of all the Deferreds it has been passed.

Here is the example with **multiple** arguments:

```js
var url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos';
var requests = [$.ajax(url), $.ajax(url)];

$.when.apply($, requests).then(function(a,b,c) {
  console.log('a', a);
  console.log('b', b);
  console.log('c', c);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note that in this case, the arguments in the callback are:

- a: Array with 3 items (JSON response, String 'success', jQuery object)
- b: Array with 3 items (JSON response, String 'success', jQuery object)
- c: undefined

If I passed a third request to when(), then c would be the result of that. It would behave consistently, no matter how many more I added.

Now look what happens when I only pass **one** request to the when() method:

```js
var url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos';
var requests = [$.ajax(url)]; // NOTE ONLY ONE

$.when.apply($, requests).then(function(a,b,c) {
  console.log('a', a);
  console.log('b', b);
  console.log('c', c);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In this case, callback's arguments don't follow the same pattern as above. Now they are:

- a: JSON response
- b: String 'success'
- c: jQuery object

Is there a clean way of doing this so that I get consistent behavior regardless of how many arguments I pass to when()?

One kludgey way I can think of to get consistent behavior would be to pass an extra dummy array to when, so that it always behaves the multiple way, like so:

```
var url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos';
var requests = [[[]], $.ajax(url)]; // Note first argument
  
$.when.apply($, requests).then(function(a,b,c) {
  console.log('a', a);
  console.log('b', b);
  console.log('c', c);
});
```

Just wondering if there's a cleaner way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the logic you want with asynchronous operations like these, I'd ditch jQuery's implementation and use `Promise.all` to do it instead:

```js
var url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos';
var requests = [$.ajax(url)]; // NOTE ONLY ONE

Promise.all(requests).then(([a]) => {
  console.log('a', a);
});
// .catch(handleErrors);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

With `Promise.all`, no matter the number of items in the array passed in, that same number of items will be in the one array parameter in the `.then` callback - whether it's one request or 10 requests.

This works with `Promise.all` because jQuery objects are thenables.